# SocketException: Permission denied: connect

Tags: java, sockets

I was wondering in what other circumstances this (SocketException: Permission denied: connect) error would be thrown from the line

```
SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("86.143.5.165", 6464);
// Set a 3s timeout
clientSocket.connect(socketAddress, 3000);
```

There are a few Android issues relating to permissions, and when using a port < 1024.
I am running a simple java client/server app, on port 6464, and i am using java 1.6.0_32 (after reading that Java 1.7.0_7 adds ipv6 support).

I have port 80 forwarded to my server (verified on the client machine by going to my external IP in a browser), and the port 6464 is open also.

Why would the client be refused connection?

EDIT: I did originally get this error when trying to connect to the server from the server itself. (Obviously, I guess it's like a telephone in that you get an engaged tone). I had a friend test it, and he could connect. I'm now connecting from a laptop that isn't on the LAN (i.e. using a 3g mobile as a hotspot), but strangely still getting the error.

EDIT2:

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at runtime.MyGame.main(MyGame.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
#### Java Web Start Error:
#### Socket failed to connect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client isn't being 'refused connection'. It is being refused *permission* to connect, by the local operating system.

IPv6 support was added in Java 1.4.

Comment: Fair comment. I'm just aware that there's been recent issues with ipv6 (on Java 7) (so that protocol's now disabled on both server and client machines; adapters restarted).

Comment: @Hemmels Post the complete stack trace in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with very localised network settings on the client. Other clients can connect without issue, I'm thinking it could be to do with workgroups, or specific local client firewalls. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

For those landing here with a similar issue to mine.

I was getting this error while running `Spock` `groovy` tests from `maven`. Running the `groovy` tests directly worked fine while running them from `maven` failed.

To solve the problem configure the `maven-surefire-plugin` to never fork.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>never</forkMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Not sure why this fixed the problem - would welcome comments.

Answer (score 0):

I got this exception when disconnecting from Cisco AnyConnect VPN version 4.10.05111.  The problem resolved the next time a connection was made.

Answer (score -1):

Well, first of all, giving us 'MyIpAsAString' and the port would be useful. Anyways, are you sure for a fact that the serve program is running on that IP and port? That would be generally why, or that your code for taking the connection in in itself is not correct.

Comment: Well, in that case, it could also just be that the computer has a firewall or something along those lines that is denying the outside request.

Comment: Added my actual IP to the question.

Comment: @VoidWhisperer I ran a dyndns port scanner. "86.143.5.165:6464 is open and accepting connections. This indicates the port is not being blocked by either a firewall or your ISP and is currently operational."

Comment: @VoidWhisperer There's no 'also' about that. It is a local permissions problem only. Nothing to do with whether the server is running or not.